# how to make this div margin to zero and more nature

Tags: html, css

I have a page here http://pastebin.com/Hva36KEn  ,and I'm new to css. How to make the #header div's margin zero and align it to page's top and make it more nature? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please put your code here, not on pastebin.

Comment: I wouldn't want all that code in the question.

Comment: It's looking fine for me in Firefox, which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `body` and `html` elements' `margin` or `padding` equal zero on them. This may cause your `#header` to be pushed down.

A bit off-topic: You wrote that you're new to CSS and that's why I thought I would include this. **Don't use inline CSS.** This is a good place to read about different ways to apply CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: it doesnt have those elements.

Comment: Yeah it does. I see <body> and <html> in your code.

Comment: how to modify it, pal! more detail please I'm not clear it

Comment: How do you figure out how to write `#header { margin: 0; padding: 0 }`, but you can't make the leap to doing the same thing for `body` or `html`?  All browsers have some form of default styling for most elements.  Just because you didn't define margin/padding doesn't mean it isn't there.